# How to remove the highlight effect when pulling a gridview to its topmost items

Tags: android

When I scroll my gridview to its topmost (bottom-most) items, and I keep trying to scroll, there's a curved semi colored effect appears on the edge (top or bottom), how to remove it? or make it fully transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set  `android:overScrollMode="never"` for `ScrollView`

Comment: Thank you and apology, I'm using a GridView (pre-set height) inside a scrollview, I added this to it but the effect still exists.

Comment: If it is in scrollview then you need to apply it too and remove for GridView

Comment: @Jack don't put the GridView inside a ScrollVIew. It makes the GridView useless